# Проблема с функцией sorted

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка

Для функции `sort` можно добавить `reverse = True` и список будет отсортирован в обратном порядке. Можно ли это сделать с функцией `sorted` и если можно то как.

Comment: Можно, атрибут также называется. Учитесь делать поиск, особенно по документации питона: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted

Comment: Какая проблема у вас возникла? У функции sorted() тоже есть аргумент “Reverse”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = []
a = sorted(a, reverse=True)  # новый list
a.sort(reverse=True)  # тот-же list
reversed(sorted(a))  # новый list as iterator
```